# How to use alphabetical bibliography instead of numerical?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to write my references as `[Harp]`, instead of `[1]`. I've read the [Bibliography Styles](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles) section on Wikibooks, but It's not clear what I should do.

Comment: In a document like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}` change  `\bibliographystyle{plain}` by `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.  That is all.

Comment: @Fran Yes, but where? I've put it anywhere and the document doesn't render.

Comment: It seems that you really need to read some basic introductory documents. There is some good basic information here: http://dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/ or see the following for `bibtex` specifically: http://www.math.utah.edu/faq/bibtex/bibtex.html.  You may also want to consider starting with `biblatex`. On this see: [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

Comment: If you still haven't settled with a particular bibliography package, I suggest `biblatex` because it's so versatile and customizable.

Comment: @Alenanno: `biblatex` can be really overwhelming, for a beginner

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think `biblatex` only appears overwhelming because there is so much older information online.  Basic use of `biblatex` really just involves getting `biber` to run in your IDE and choosing an appropriate style.  And then if you do need changes, there are quite a few of us here who can help quite quickly with customization.

Comment: @AlanMunn: IDE? I don't use an IDE ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I used `natbib` only for a short time, until it felt insufficient and switched to `biblatex`. Whatever I don't know, I search on here or the internet. :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're using biblatex with bibtex, something like:

```
usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=anyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

in the preamble (i.e. before \begin{document}, where you already have \usepackage[...]{biblatex}

If you're using bibtex, you should have somewhere in your document (i.e. after \begin{document})

```
\bibliography{<somefilename>}
```

specify the citation style just before:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{dabib}
```

EDIT:

(cutting the original entry from the document server to get rid of greek letters, which are a matter on their own)
mybib.bib:

```
@article{Aaij:2015tga,
  author         = "Aaij, Roel and others",
  title          = "{Observation of Letters}",
  collaboration  = "LHCb",
  journal        = "Phys. Rev. Lett.",
  volume         = "115",
  year           = "2015",
  pages          = "072001",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.072001",
  eprint         = "1507.03414",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
  reportNumber   = "CERN-PH-EP-2015-153, LHCB-PAPER-2015-029",
  SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1507.03414;%%"
}
```

version 1:
main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=anyt,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}
Here I cite \cite{Aaij:2015tga}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

run with e.g. `pdflatex main; bibtex main; pdflatex main; pdflatex main`

version 2:
main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=anyt,style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}
Here I cite \cite{Aaij:2015tga}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

run with e.g. `pdflatex main; biber main; pdflatex main; pdflatex main`

version 3:
main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here I cite \cite{Aaij:2015tga}.
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

run with e.g. `pdflatex main; bibtex main; pdflatex main; pdflatex main`

I agree with the others that you should prefer the `biblatex` package over not using it (i.e. not version 3). As obvious from the initial version, I haven't migrated to `biber` myself, so cannot comment on its advantages.

I provided version 3 in case your document is not using `biblatex` so far and is too involved to migrate now.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx.  This answer kind of mixes up two systems since Bibtex is both a `.bib` file format and a program, and `biblatex` is a package.  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701). Also,  so perhaps you want to specify minimal documents for each type, which would make the answer much clearer.  Also, since `biblatex` increasingly relies on Biber as the backend, I would not recommend using `bibtex` as the backend for new users especially.

Comment: +1 just one minor point: The `\bibliography` command in `biblatex` is deprecated (although still works) and should be replaced by `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}` (`.bib` extension required.)